# Prestashop - set different prices according to payment method?

Tags: prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.5.6 and I'd need to set a different total price for an order depending on the chosen method, some modules work intermediating with credit cards (like Mercado Pago module) and I'd need to increase the price in that case, is this possible to do it with the functionality of the shop itself, is there a module , a workaround or something? The module of the payment method I need to increase the price doesn't allow to be configured in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not supported by PrestaShop up to 1.5.6. So far PrestaShop 1.6 will not support that either. You will need to search for a module for that.

This module claims to support that feature:
http://addons.prestashop.com/en/checkout-modules/3495-additional-payment-fees.html
but one client that uses it said it's not working properly and they had to tweak the core Moneybookers & PayPal modules to add fees feature. Also the developer did not respond very friendly when issues were reported, so it's up to you if you'll use it or will search for another.

Comment: I actually hacked a module for adding a fee, but Im not quite sure if Im allowed to do that, do you think that if before selecting a paymenth you display a message next to the payment mentioning you are going to add a fee, and hacking the module for doing so it would be alright? The module is for using a latinamerican payment method and they dont mention anywhere if you can hack in the module before sending values to the API or not

Comment: btw, Im getting better information here about this than in the official forums lol

Comment: It's ok to hack the module as far as you hack it on 2 places:
1) When sending the price to the Payment Gateway
2) When Payment Gateway validates the paid price with the grand total of the order.

Usually the Payment Gateway calls URL from your site (usually part of the module i.e. in your module dir) to validate that the paid price is equal to the total of the order.

Of course you should inform your customers that a fee will be added before they click on the payment method - in the template file displayed at hookPayment() method.

Comment: When I was searching for answers to similar question, one of the first pages that comes up on Google is this one and the answers here are from 2013 so I have for you a link to different module that does the same thing and works with the current Prestashop versions:

https://addons.prestashop.com/28289-payment-with-fee-custom-payment-methods.html

Maybe it will help someone.