# What is the procedure to add add extra fee for any payment gateway module in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, payment

How to add extra payment fee for using any payment gateway with EMI option in prestashop ?

Comment: We can't answer to your question because is too extensive. You have to make or pick up (maybe buy) a module.

Comment: can you post your example, i'm interested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prestashop - set different prices according to payment method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789097/prestashop-set-different-prices-according-to-payment-method)