# How to add a fee to COD payment method Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, payment, fee

I need to charge a fee on COD payment method but since my project has been changed much time for other programmers, I'm not really sure where should I apply it in the source.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789097/prestashop-set-different-prices-according-to-payment-method/50176957?noredirect=1#comment87371274_50176957)

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to where you're trying to make a change, what changes you've attempted, and what's not working the way you expect?

Comment: i've not really attempted much because i'm kinda noob at prestashop.
i've been on classes/cart and i wanted to add the tax value to cart total price, but i dont have a reference to the payment option because it can even not been picked yet.
So i need to change a file that knows the carrier, the payment option, and the cart total value, so i can make
    if(carrier==x and payment_option==y)
    {
        total+= codTax;
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prestashop - set different prices according to payment method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789097/prestashop-set-different-prices-according-to-payment-method)